# Lazy.js: zipping with a range

Tags: javascript, lazy.js

I'd like to zip together a count with an array. It seems something like this would be the most elegant way of doing it `Lazy([...]).zip(Lazy.range(1, Infinity))`. But it doesn't produce the result I expect. Here is a unit test:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var Lazy = require('lazy.js');

describe('Lazy', () => {
  describe('#zip()', () => {
    it('can zip with infinite range', () => {
      assert.deepEqual([['a', 1], ['b', 2]],
        Lazy(['a', 'b']).zip(Lazy.range(1, Infinity)).toArray());
    });
  });
});
```

It fails with the following error:

```
AssertionError: [ [ 'a', 'b' ], [ 1, 2 ] ] deepEqual [ [ 'a', undefined ], [ 'b', undefined ] ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `Lazy.zip` only accepts `Array` parameters [0] [1], and `Lazy.range()` produces a `GeneratedSequence`.

This does seem a little unintuitive in a library designed for, well, laziness.

I suppose you could do something like

```
Lazy(arr).zip(Lazy.range(1, arr.length + 1).toArray()).toArray()
```

Incidentally, `zip` should produce `[['a', 1], ['b', 2]]`, as opposed to `[['a', 'b'], [1, 2]]`, which unless I'm mistaken is what you're currently testing for.

**Edit:** Since you're converting to an array in the end anyway, have you considered just using the native `Array.map`?

```
arr.map((x, i) => [x, i + 1]);
```

--

[0] http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/docs/#Sequence-zip

[1] https://github.com/dtao/lazy.js/issues/87

Comment: I didn't know the native map also gave you an index parameter. Thanks!